# Highcharts changing data granularity in combined charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes/sand-signika/

What I am trying to do is: to change the granularity of line chart. For example. I want to plot a weekly data points on line chart while sticking with monthly bar charts.

Can someone please suggest if this is doable or if anyone has tried that in past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning I advice to use [datetime xAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type). Distance between points, you can control by [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval)